# VS 2017 .csproj behaving weird

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I add new folder under my console application, the `project .csproj` file gets updated and shows:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="test\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I further add a sub-folder, the `project .csproj` is again updated with the following hierarchy:

```
<Folder Include="test\test2\" />
```

But if I create `.html` folder under the `test2` folder, the whole entry `<Folder Include="test\test2\" />` gets removed from `project .csproj.`

Is this normal?

In earlier version of `VS2013`, the .`csproj` did contain information about the files and folders added to that project.

e.g.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app\test1\test2\test3\myfile.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Do I need to still maintain this information in .csproj?

Comment: Yes it's normal. All files are i cluded by default. Empty folders can't be included (technical reasons of which I can not give you a definite answer) so have to have a definition in your csproj file!

Comment: didn't get you ! adding .html filder under test1\test2 folder. Which folder is empty in this case?

Comment: He said that it was empty before you added .html, that's the reason it was included to .csproj. If it isn't empty, it shouln't be in .csproj, because files are included by default.